# How many different modifier keys can we have on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, chorded-keyboard

I'm digging the [chorded keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard) info and trying to understand to what extent is that possible on an average desktop with the standard keyboard.

This question is purely about number of different modifiers and maybe their unique combinations regardless of their position.

Using two standard keyboards... allowed.

Related:

https://askubuntu.com/q/264109/20275

[making any key into a modifier key](https://askubuntu.com/q/33751/20275)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question but, without n-key rollover using PS/2 you can only have 4 modifier keys per keyboard.

Excerpt from [this](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html) article.

PS/2 vs USB Technical Limitations

Keep the following in mind if you have an n-key rollover keyboard that can be hooked up to your computer through either USB or a PS/2 port:

USB protocol limitation - A max of 10 simultaneous key presses are recognized, 6 non-modifier keys ('w', 'a', 's', 'd', etc) + 4 modifier keys (Shift, Caps, Ctrl, etc).  Although you are limited to 6 regular keys you are still guaranteed that any combination of keys will be recognized properly if you have an n-key rollover keyboard. I would guess that most people would not need support for more keys than this. I would also guess that the 6 key limit may have had something to do with braille input requirements rather than someone choosing an arbitrary limit (although that doesn't explain why the limit exists in the first place).
    PS/2 - There are no limitations when using a PS/2 connection with your keyboard. You will truly get full n-key rollover support.

So using 2 standard keyboards without without PS/2, I think that you could have a maximum of 8 modifier keys.